# Multiple find and replace in string

Tags: javascript

I have a string that looks like this,

```
Joe Bloggs created the {project}Joe Project 1{/project} and created the brief {object}Brief Number 1{/object}
```

I want to turn this into a string of HTML that would looks like this,

```
Joe Bloggs created the <a href="" class="project-link">Joe Project 1</a> and created the brief <a href="" class="object-link">Brief Number 1</a>
```

I know I can do this,

```
var string = "Joe Bloggs created the {project}Joe Project 1{/project} and created the brief {object}Brief Number 1{/object}";
string.replace("{project}", "<a href='' class='project-link'>");
string.replace("{/project}", "</a>");
string.replace("{object}", "<a href='' class='object-link'>");
string.replace("{/object}", "</a>");
```

This does not feel particularly succinct though, is there a nicer way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a single RegEx

```
str.replace(/{(project|object)}(.*?){\/\1}/gi, '<a href="" class="$1-link">$2</a>')
```

**Explanation:**

1. `{(project|object)}`: Match `project` or `object` string wrapped in curly braces. Add the string in first captured group.
2. `(.*?)`: Match anything lazily to satisfy the condition
3. `{\/\1}`: `\1` here is the back-reference of the first captured group. Thus, if the first captured group contains `object` this will match `{/object}`.
4. `gi`: `g` is to match all possible strings. `i` is to match case-insensitively.
5. `$1` and `$2` in the replacement part are the first and second captured groups respectively.

```js
var str = 'Joe Bloggs created the {project}Joe Project 1{/project} and created the brief {object}Brief Number 1{/object}';

var result = str.replace(/{(project|object)}(.*?){\/\1}/gi, '<a href="" class="$1-link">$2</a>');

console.log(result);
document.body.textContent = result; // For showing result on page

document.body.innerHTML += '<hr />' + result; // For showing HTML on page
```

---

The RegEx can made short as

[**`{((?:pro|ob)ject)}(.*?){\/\1}`**](https://regex101.com/r/iS3sK2/1)

Answer (score 1):

regex is your friend:

```js
var string = "Joe Bloggs created the {project}Joe Project 1{/project} and created the brief {object}Brief Number 1{/object}";

string = string.replace(/{\/\w+}/g, "</a>"); //with this you strip out closing tag

string = string.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m,m2) {
  return "<a href='' class='" + m2 + "-link'>"
})//this part will wrap whatever inside the opening braces in to your desired markup

console.log(string)
```

Comment: @Tushar I saw that

Answer (score 0):

There are templating libraries that exist for this purpose. Check out the handlebars templating library to get started (there are lots and lots to choose from).

http://handlebarsjs.com/

Comment: I wouldn't recommend introducing a custom DSL for rendering markup when there is existing software that fulfills this use case.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.validator.format("Joe Bloggs created the {0}Joe Project 1{1} and created the brief {2}Brief Number 1{1}", "<a href='' class='project-link'>","</a>","<a href='' class='object-link'>")
```

Source: http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.format/

Comment: OP didn't say he's using validator or even jQuery.